# Laravel 5.4 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship

I have a problem with a relationship hasMany. This is my code:

In the model Document, I have:

```
public function aliases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Alias');
}
```

In model Alias:

```
public function document()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document');
}
```

In the Controller, I’ve made a foreach to avoid having a collection:

```
$data['aliases'] = [];
$aliases = Alias::where('path', $directory)->get();
if(null != $aliases){
    foreach($aliases as $alias){
        $data['aliases'][] = $alias;
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
if(isset($data['aliases']))
    @foreach($data['aliases'] as $alias)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! HTML::image('images/panel/icons/alias.svg', '', array('class' => 'icons_type')) !!}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('documents.show', '', $alias->doc_id) }}">{!! $alias->document->name !!}</a></td>
            <td>{{--{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($alias->document->date)) !!}--}}</td>
            <td>{{--{!! $alias->document->class !!}--}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The problem is when I try to get the property name or another property trough of relationship document() in the view:

```
$alias->document->name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data array code in the controller does not solve anything? Why would you want to convert a collection (which implements the ArrayAccess interface) to an array?

And by setting:

```
$data['aliases'] = [];
```

This statement will always be true:

```
if(isset($data['aliases']))
```

The issue you have is that you are requesting the name from a non-object, there is no document for the alias there.

I see that you use `$alias->doc_id` in the view, I assume that this is the Document model foreign key on the Alias model, doc_id is not according to the naming convention and will not auto resolve. If not defined, Laravel expects it to be `document_id`. You use `doc_id` as the foreign key, which is not according the naming conventions, so you have to define it.

Try this:

```
public function aliases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Alias', 'doc_id');
}




public function document()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'doc_id');
}
```

For more info see: [Laravel - One-to-many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Also checkout eager loading (saves queries) and if an alias can exist without a document, you should check if the document exists in your foreach before you try to access properties of the document.

Comment: It's work! I though that if you defined other foreign key instead Laravel expected in the migrations, you don´t need to define it in the relationship. I was wrong. Thank you Robert! I convert the collection in an array because if not I couldn´t take the property: $alias->doc_id directely. Maybe there is another way.